# Call a tikzset macro explicitely with the default value

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a macro of the following form:

```
\tikzset{
    foo/.style 2 args={
        ...
    },
    foo/.default={2pt}{}
}
```

If I do not want to specify any argument, I can use `foo`. If I want to specify the first argument, I can use `foo={3pt}` (EDIT: in this case, the second argument is empty). If I want to specify both arguments, I can write `foo={3pt}{green}`.

Now I want to call `foo`, use the default value for the first argument and specify a value for the second argument. Is this possible ?

Something like `foo={default}{green}`.

Comment: `foo={3pt}` will not behave the way you suggested -- it always makes the second argument empty no matter what the second argument default is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This implements a handler called `/.default 2 args` that has the requested behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{/handlers/.default 2 args/.code 2 args={%
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@def}{{#1}{#2}}
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@def1}{{#1}}
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@def2}{{#2}}
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd}{\temp}
    \pgfkeyslet{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd@orig}{\temp}
    \pgfkeysdefargs{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{##1##2}{
        \def\tempa{##1}\def\tempb{##2}\def\tempc{default}%
        \ifx\tempa\tempc
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@def1}{\temparga}%
        \else
            \def\temparga{{##1}}%
        \fi
        \ifx\tempb\tempc
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@def2}{\tempargb}%
        \else
            \def\tempargb{{##2}}%
        \fi
        \csname pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd@orig\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter\temparga\tempargb\pgfeov
    }
}}

\begin{document}


\pgfkeys{
    foo/.code 2 args={(#1)(#2)},
    foo/.default 2 args={2pt}{1pt},
    foo={a}{b},
    foo={a}{default},
    foo={default}{b},
    foo
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, although the use of multi-argument keys is generally against the spirit of the interface, is it not? ;)

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I believe there is nothing simpler or more built-in? I was looking more for a keyword I did not know, but this does not seem as simple as I thought.

Comment: Yeah I've read the section of the pgf manual on pgfkeys quite a few times. There is nothing built-in to handle default arguments for multi-argument keys.